# Azure service fabric cluster provisioning questions

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Once I create the azure service fabric cluster through azure portal, I am not sure how long I am supposed to wait for the cluster to be up and running. I am only using bare minimum configuration (with node type count 1 and bronze model with 3 VMs etc.) Will take an hour or 2 or more or less? Will there be some kind of indication that cluster deployment is done and is available for me to publish code from visual studio? Also I am not seeing any nodes in the provisioned cluster in the portal.

Thanks.
Raghu/..

Comment: It has been sitting with following status after 4 hours: "Waiting for nodes". Also I found this in the Audit logs: statusCode:Conflict statusMessage:{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"ResourceDeploymentFailure","message":"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.","details":[{"code":"VMScaleSetAllocationError","message":"OS Provisioning for VM 'MyNodeTypeQueue_0' did not finish in the allotted time. The VM may still finish provisioning successfully. Please check provisioning state later."}]}}

Comment: Did you choose a VM type with dedicated disk space? While you have a broad choice of VM types we couldn't get it working without one with dedicated disk space. It should take 5-10 minutes and you'll get a notification to say it has been deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per mckjerral, I changed my VM Size type from A1 standard to DS1 standard and also to reliability tier from Bronze to Silver type, it deployed successfully and I was able to publish my service fabric app to it. Thank you for your help.

Raghu/..