# Secure Service Fabric creation stuck in waiting for nodes status

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have created SF Cluster Linux Preview through automation script .

Steps :

1. Create a resource group ( location eastus)
2. Created keyvault under the resource group
3. Set policy --enabled-for-deployment 'true' --enabled-for-template-deployment 'true'
4. Uploaded the certificate to keyvault
5. Created Service Fabric cluster with node type 2 ( D2_V2 , Durability - Bronze, Reliability -Silver)

After deployment nodes are not joined the SF Cluster . it is stuck in 'waiting for nodes' status.

Is it related to authentication issue for nodes to join ?

Related Stackoverflow questions: 
[Azure service fabric cluster provisioning questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438519/azure-service-fabric-cluster-provisioning-questions/36457991)
But this does not solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to invalid certificate thumbprint. 
I was using the following command (sha256) for getting the certificate thumbprint in my script

```
CERT_THUMB=$(openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -sha256 -fingerprint | awk -F= '{print $NF}' | sed -e 's/://g')
```

As explained here https://github.com/ChackDan/Service-Fabric/blob/master/Scripts/CertUpload4Linux/CreateAndUploadtoKeyvault.md

But then when I checked cert_helper.py script in the same project. I found that it was generating thumbprint without using -sha256

```
CERT_THUMB=$(openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -fingerprint | awk -F= '{print $NF}' | sed -e 's/://g')
```